# Entity framework raw SQL Query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have to select multiple columns from a database and I don't have a matching entity.
so my query looks like this:

```
var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(
             "select ID, NAME, DB_FIELD from eis_hierarchy");
```

I am getting the result set, each row contains list of strings but count is 0.

So how do I select multiple columns using `Database.SqlQuery`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to capture the results into a class with matching property names, and (at least) a parameterless constructor:

```
class DbResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string DB_FIELD { get; set; }
}

var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbResult>(
                 "select ID, NAME, DB_FIELD from eis_hierarchy");
```

Comment: I found this to work well--except when the SP result field has a name like "unallocated space", which obviously can't be used as a .NET property name. Anyone have an idea what to do in that case?

Comment: Probably use an alias: `select [unallocated space] AS unallocated_space from Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Using C# version higher than 6, it can be written in this way as well:

```
var result = _dbContext.Database.
                SqlQuery<(int ID, string NAME, string DB_FIELD)>("select ID, NAME, DB_FIELD from eis_hierarchy");
```