# KeyValuePair from running Raw SQL query on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have the following query and code running and I want the two columns returned on a KeyValuePair. I see the total row returned is right but all the keyvaluepairs are nul !

```
string query = @"Select id,name from persons";

var persons = context.Database.SqlQuery<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(query);
```

I have seen an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096519/entity-framework-raw-sql-query) saying that I have to create a class to get the result; but my question is can't I get the result on KeyValuePair ? Or I must have a class defined with properties matched ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that [`KeyValuePair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3db765db%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have a parameterless constructor. EF materializes an object by first creating one (by its parameterless constructor) and then setting its properties.

Answer (score 3):

create your pair class

```
public class KeyIntValueString {
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
string sql = "SELECT RoleId AS [Key], RoleName AS [Value] FROM dbo.webpages_Roles";
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> roles = db.Database.SqlQuery<KeyIntValueString>(sql)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(f => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(f.Key, f.Value))
              .ToList();
```

and, for example in case of mvc view, use KeyValuePair

```
@model IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
...
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Key)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i believe the column names need to match some property of the type you are attempting to assign it to.

can you try changing the query to `@"Select id as Key, name as Value from persons";` although i think it might be easier to just create a POCO class to project the results into

edit
You cant use KeyValuePair in the manner because:

```
The type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.String]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.
```

you should ask yourself a few questions:

- why am i writing inline sql when using entity framework?
- why can i not have a class/struct that can be used to store the results of this query?

I think the real answer is create at least a class to store into:

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

var persons = context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(@"Select id, name from persons");
```

Comment: why am i writing inline sql when using entity framework? Because the SQL I write has its specialists and complexities. EF can only do plain SQL...