# Why does EntityFramework Raw SqlQuery returns objects from MySql with undesired values?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

When I am running a RawSqlQuery against a DBContext to get a List Objects from a MySql database, the objects are not being returned with their real values in database. All objects in the list are having default values for all the properties after query.

**Code:**

```
using (var dbContext=new PartnerEntities())
        {
            string sql = $@"select idcall,starttime from cdr limit 0,100";
            List<KeyValuePair<long,DateTime>> rowIdVsDates =
                dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<KeyValuePair<long,DateTime>>(sql).ToList();
        }
```

**Result retrieved:**
[Results from debug:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMl5O.png)

**Original Data:**
**idcall, starttime**                       
1, '2017-12-01 22:56:38'  
2, '2017-12-01 22:56:33'  
3, '2017-12-01 22:56:44'  
4, '2017-12-01 22:56:14'  
5, '2017-12-01 22:56:49'  
6, '2017-12-01 22:56:34'  
7, '2017-12-01 22:56:41'  
8, '2017-12-01 22:56:25'  
9, '2017-12-01 22:56:39'

As per the EF doc, what I am trying to achieve should be possible.
[EF Documentation from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

From the link:

> *A SQL query returning instances **of any type**, including primitive types, can be created using the SqlQuery method on the Database class.
>   For example: using (var context = new BloggingContext())  { 
>       var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery( 
>                          "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();  }*

I was using EntityFramework 6.1.3 with C#, MySql 5.6 for windows, connector .net 6.9.8. I updated EF to 6.2.0 (latest) but this didn't solve the problem.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: In my experience, the MySQL connectors for .net have been very questionable. Eventually I found the need to move away from them. I would suggest hooking this up to a test MSSQL database, using the SqlProvider, and seeing if that generates a proper data set. If it does, then there is a bug in the MySQL connector, and not Entity Framework.

Comment: yea MySQL connector seems pretty buggy. I only use the raw sql option (no EF)

Comment: Your problem is with `KeyValuePair` which can't be used with `SqlQuery` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28047040/2557128); you should create your own class or return something (`ValueTuple`?)and use LINQ `Select` to convert it to `KeyValuePair` - you also need property setters that match the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyValue pair type is incorrect.  It matches on property name. You should use a custom type instead.  For example:

**EDIT**: Changed the types to match your use case

```
public class MyDto
{
    public int IdCall { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query will look like this:

```
var rowIdVsDates = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyDto>(sql).ToList();
```

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer, but the column names in the raw Sql Query must match the property names of the class (myDto), so column aliases should be used in Sql if required, like in this case:

string sql = $@"select idcall as IdCall,starttime as StartTime from cdr limit 0,100";

Tested this & everything works.