# Entity Framework - sort by SQL function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-function

Is it possible to sort in Entity Framework by sql function from database?
I mean something like:

```cs
 var xx = DbContext.Set<Article>()
      .Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("X")).OrderBy("[dbo].[MySQLFunction]");
```

Comment: I think, you should use raw query in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096519/entity-framework-raw-sql-query

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not possible and you can't mix LINQ/delta notation with SQL although you can use SQL queries via EF. Can you add you're SQLFunction as a C# function?

Comment: I have to take same data with paging but it should be sorted by complex function . I think I could write it in multiple complex expressions, but can't merge into one expression.

Comment: To add more details: I have to use Code First (so, without TVF) and SQL function which uses parameters.

Answer (score 3):

```
var xx = DbContext.Set<Article>()
      .Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("X"))
      .Select(x=> new 
        {
           Article = x,
           orderItem = SqlFunction.//Any function you want to use.
                                   // Or may you want to use DbFunctions               
        })
      .OrderBy(x=>x.orderItem);
```

Here is more information about [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

***Update:***

By the way, if you mean to use your custom SQLFunction then I advise you to make a **computed column** in your table and make this column use this SQLFunction then you could OrderBy or filter against this field using normal Linq queries

Comment: I use Code First so I cant write complex computed column property which executes SQL Function (with parameters).

Answer (score 1):

The only option I found - is something like bad workaround, and I guess this is limited to simple queries.

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext;
var query = (System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)objectContext.CreateObjectSet<User>().Where(u => u.Id != Guid.Empty);

var initialQueryString = query.ToTraceString();
var resultQueryString = initialQueryString + " order by [dbo].[MySQLFunction]";

//careful here, if you use MS SQL you need to use SqlParameter instead of NpgsqlParameter
var paramValues = new List<NpgsqlParameter>();
foreach (var param in query.Parameters)
{
    paramValues.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(param.Name, param.Value));
}

var result = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<User>(resultQueryString, paramValues.Cast<object>().ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: It's very interesting but as you mention, only for not very complex query and it's a little risky :)

Comment: @foxiter yeap, but still very strange we can't do that by dynamic linq or something like that