# How do I execute RAW SQL query and dump it to JSON in ASP.NET MVC 5 (EF 6)?

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I want to execute a raw SQL query as shown below:

```
select material, method, count(*) 
from treatment 
group by material, method
```

and return it as a JSON object.

Because EF 6 allows the execution of raw query (i.e., `Database.SQLQuery()`), I use it to create a JSON Object.

My code looks like this.

```
// GET: Dummy
public string Dummy()
{
    string query = "select material, method, count(*) as cnt from Treatment "
                   + " group by material, method";
    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<List<String>>(query);
    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

    return jsonResult;
}
```

However, instead of getting a JSON object with the material and methods, I get an empty json object instead.

```
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Is it possible to return the correct JSON object without having the model for the the raw query? If so, how to update my code to return the correct result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your result has data in it? By the looks of it, it appears that the result was empty? I know it sounds obvious, but just step through the code and check if result contains anything?

Comment: Yes. There are several row of data in the table and the amount of empty JSON object created is the same number of rows of the result.

Comment: try chaning `db.Database.SqlQuery<List<String>>(query)` to `db.Database.SqlQuery<List<object>>(query)`.

Comment: I still get the same result

Comment: `List<String>` only returns single list of strings while your query has 3 data sets. What do you mean of "without having the model" - are you don't want to create additional class with properties to handle query result before converting to JSON?

Comment: Hi, thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto, from your question, I found out the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't resolve that query to a list of strings, you need to resolve it to a (list of) class(es), like this :

```
public static string Dummy()
{
    using (var db = new TestDbEntities())
    {
        string query = "select 'material' as material , 'method' as method, 1  as cnt  ";
        var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(query);
        var res = result.ToList();
        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
        return jsonResult;
    }
}
```

where your class will be something like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Material { get; set; }

    public string Method { get; set; }

    public int Cnt { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture query result sets with multiple columns using a class with matching property names (make sure they have exactly same name and proper casing) and parameterless constructor:

```
public string Dummy()
{
    string query = "select material as Material, method as Method, count(*) as Cnt from Treatment group by material, method";
    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ResultSet>(query).ToList();
    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    return jsonResult;
}

public class ResultSet
{
    public string Material { get; set; }

    public string Method { get; set; }

    public int Cnt { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `Database.SqlQuery<T>` will return an `IEnumerable<T>` with type `System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery<T>`, so that a `List<string>` is not fit in this context. If you just return single result set, `Database.SqlQuery<string>(...).ToList()` should be used instead of `Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>`.

Similar issue:

[Entity framework raw SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096519/entity-framework-raw-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use FOR JSON AUTO:

```
     string query = "select material, method, count(*) as cnt from Treatment "
        + " group by material, method FOR JSON AUTO";
```